# How to open terminal, print to it, and close it in .jar application

Tags: java, io

I have a program where, during a long task, I use System.out to print messages to indicate its progress. However, this can only be seen in the terminal in Visual Studio Code.

When I export the program to a jar file and double-click it, it doesn't print out any System.out messages, although it is still able to do its tasks.

So, how do I make my program open a terminal upon double-clicking its jar file so that it can print messages to it in a similar manner as using System.out?

Comment: It's running a gui?  You could "redirect" the `System.out` and capture it, then print it to some other window

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change where stderr and stdout go:

```
public class RedirectStdStreams {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setOut( new PrintStream( "/tmp/stdout" ) );
        System.setErr( new PrintStream( "/tmp/stderr" ) );

        System.out.println( "Look ma, watch me juggle this chainsaw!" );
        System.err.println( "Uh oh, that didn't go well at all...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running with java cli. This is basically what your IDE does when you run your project.

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

If you don't want to keep your console open and still persist logs, I would suggest using log4j or just simply [redirect output of System.out to file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redirecting-system-out-println-output-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: More specifically, the IDE also provides the terminal that is utilized for input/output. When you doubleclick a jar file in windows, the jar is executed using `java -jar`, but no terminal is shown, which is the actual issue here.

Comment: [Java SE has a perfectly good logging system.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)  No need to rely on a shoddy dependency like Log4J.